# C# async subsequent calls return existing task

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have web application which calls an external API for data.

If a user triggers this external call, and the call is already in effect, I don't want a second request to trigger a new call, but instead wait for the result of the first call (the result of the call will be the same for both requests).

How can I achieve this in c# using async/ await?

Comment: How persistent should the result be? If the second call comes in hours later, should it still use the result the first call obtained or start a new one?

Comment: This may help: https://alastaircrabtree.com/cache-the-result-of-an-async-method-using-lazycache/ or this: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/asynclazyt/

Comment: There is a known period for which the results are "fresh", after this time I need to call again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> subsequent calls return existing task

Sure, you can do that just by keeping the `Task<T>` object and then returning it.

Something like:

```
private async Task<T> ImplementationAsync();
private Task<T> _task;

public Task<T> InterfaceAsync()
{
  if (_task == null)
    _task = ImplementationAsync();
  return _task;
}
```

This is an extremely simple example. Real-world code should consider:

- Can `InterfaceAsync` be called from multiple threads? If so, then `_task` needs to be protected.
- Is this code loading a resource only one time? If so, then consider using [`AsyncLazy<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.threading.asynclazy-1) instead of `Task<T>`.
- Should this code re-load the resource on the next call if the old call has already completed? If so, then the cached `Task<T>`/`AsyncLazy<T>` needs to be replaced when the call completes.
- Is caching errors OK, or should the next call always retry any previous errors?